# Cordova FileTransfer code:3 "Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm capturing images in an Ionic/Android app using Cordova Camera plugin, and trying to transfer the images to a PHP API using Cordova FileTransfer plugin. This is code:

```
    uploadImage( imgSource: string, id: string ) {
        
        var ulrTarget: any;
        
        const options: FileUploadOptions = {
            fileKey: 'image',
            chunkedMode: false,
            headers: {
                Connection: "close"
            }       
        };
        
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this._fileTransfer.create();

        ulrTarget = `${this.url}upload-image`;
        console.log(ulrTarget); // "http://192.168.0.26:80/susalud/api/public/upload-image"
        console.log(imgSource); // "http://localhost/_app_file_/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/IMG-20220128-WA0003.jpg"
    
        fileTransfer.upload( imgSource,  encodeURI(ulrTarget), options, true )
            .then( data => {
            console.log('Image Sent : ',data);
            }).catch( err => {
            console.log('Upload Error : ', err);
            });
    }
```

The API receives the post http request, but $_FILES is empty.

At the app side the fileTransfer returs a code 3 "Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80" error message as follows:

```
Upload Error : 
{
    "code": 3,
    "source": "http://localhost/_app_file_/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/IMG-20220128-WA0003.jpg",
    "target": "http://192.168.0.26:80/susalud/api/public/upload-image",
    "http_status": 500,
    "body": "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'><title>Error</title></head><body><h1>Upload Error...Empty File...</h1><br/></body></html>",
    "exception": "Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80"
}
```

I have cleared CORS, permission, and cleartextTraffic issues.

I've made other test: running this in page.html the image is shown properly in Android:

```
      <ion-card>
        <img [src]="imgSource">
      </ion-card>
```

Following my network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"></base-config> 
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.26</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Any help will be more than welcome
Best
Daniel

Comment: `"source": "http://localhost/_app_file_/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/IMG-20220128-WA0003.jpg` That should be: `"source": "/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/IMG-20220128-WA0003.jpg`

Comment: Thank you @blackapps, but didn't work, now is a  `code: 1
exception: "/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/IMG-20220128-WA0003.jpg"`. As the app runs in a WebView enviroment, I understand that the image have to be accessed as a localhost URL...

Comment: Add file:// before that path. And enable file access.

Comment: Thank you @blackapps, I have tried `file://data/...` and `file:///data/...` with the same error code 1 result

Comment: @blackapp: you were right!!.  The solution to error code 3 was using `file:///data/...` for the image URI... then, the error code 1 resulted to be because of a typo producing a mismatch in the keyFile sent against what the server was expecting. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!